# Cron Job Update

Tags: linux, cron

I have two files under /etc/cron.d/ named j1 and j2.
I make changes to those files, and in a little file the changes are gone and I don't seem to figure out who/what reverts the changes.

Is there a way to see what process/app/script did the change?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it for sure getting changed? Umm.... a program that constantly watches the files in question for any changes, like `tail -f` might spot the change when it happens, not sure about what changed it though. I'll bet there exists a program in debian's repos that may work, searched there?

Comment: Hi! Actually I did a lot of searching and came across an auditing daemon in 2.6.x. Experimenting with that right now...

Answer (score 0):

These programs should watch files for changes, I haven't investigated them to see if they can tell what changes the files, but they were hits (or related) to a Ubuntu package search for [what changed file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&section=all&arch=any&keywords=what%20changed%20file&searchon=all)

- [Changetrack](http://changetrack.sourceforge.net/) (or at [ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/changetrack)

  > Changetrack logs modifications of a set of files, and allows recovery of the tracked files from any stage of development. The changes are presented in a powerful web-based form, a text file, or an email message. A handful of options allow situation-specific configuration, but the code is readily available for more complex modifications.
- [Diffmon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/diffmon)

  > Tool for reporting changes in system configuration
- [filetraq](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/filetraq)

  > Small utility to keep track of changes in config files

Comment: (would've posted 2hrs ago but couldn't)